# Is there a way to extract the section before the first `/` from a list?

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, split

I have a list of URLs:

> URL = ['ose.co.jp/frame.html', 'tse.or.jp/english/individuals/index.html', 'traderupdates.nyse.com/?sa_campaign=/internal_ads/callouts/traderupdates']

I thought of using split('/'), but realized that it doesn't really solve the problem because I would still have to delete the portion of the URL after '/'.

The result that I am looking for is:

```
URL = ['ose.co.jp', 'tse.or.jp', traderupdates.nyse.com']
```

Comment: I can't quite make out what your asking for, can you include the desired output?  Are you looking for the *host portion* of the above uris?

Comment: @TokenMacGuy: Updated. Hope this clarifies the question. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If I'm not misunderstanding the question, I believe this will work fine:

```
for i in URL:
    a = i.split('/')[0]
    #do something
```

Edit: If that is your desired output, then

```
URL = [i.split('/')[0] for i in URL]
```

Will give you what you want.

Comment: if you are only interested in the first item out of the list returned by `str.split`, you should pass the number of splits you want, ie `i.split('/', 1)[0]` so that it doesn't waste any extra effort splitting the unused portion of the input string.

Comment: @TokenMacGuy possible alternative is `str.partition` (I've never decided if it's clearer, but is almost akin to a `str.split(whatever, 1)`

Comment: @JonClements: The main point of `partition` is that it returns the a 3-tuple including the separator. So I think the rule of thumb is: When you want the separator, use `partition`; when you don't, use `split`.

Comment: @abarnert Actually - it's just come back to me now what the main difference is (it's been new years - celebrations and all that malarky - head needs to get back into gear!). `str.partition` as you say returns a 3-tuple, but it's guaranteed to do so. So although it doesn't apply in this case - `'123'.split('x', 1)[1]` will throw `IndexError` while `'123'.partition('x')[2]` will get you an empty string...

Answer (score 1):

If you are only interested in the first item in the list, you can look forward to use [str.partition](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.partition).

Here would be an implementation of using it

```
>>> URL = ['ose.co.jp/frame.html', 'tse.or.jp/english/individuals/index.html', 'traderupdates.nyse.com/?sa_campaign=/internal_ads/callouts/traderupdates']
>>> [e.partition("/")[0] for e in URL]
['ose.co.jp', 'tse.or.jp', 'traderupdates.nyse.com']
```